# how to JavaScript For Loop adding prompt boxes?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have made a while loop which allows prompt boxes to be summed up and the largest number is displayed. I am trying to convert the While loop to a For loop. I am having trouble with this as I pretty much dont know anything about For loops, any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```js
var a = Number(prompt("Enter First Number"));
var b = Number(prompt("Enter Second Number"));
var c = Number(prompt("Enter Third Number"));

while (a > 0) {
  if (a > b && a > c) {
    alert(prompt("A is Bigger"));
  }
  if (b > a && b > c) {
    alert(prompt("B is Bigger"));
  }
  if (c > a && c > b) {
    alert(prompt("C is Bigger"));
  } else {
    alert(prompt("Each number is the same"))
  }
  alert(prompt(a + b + c));
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to convert this to a for loop

Comment: `alert(prompt())` is a very strange construct. You're prompting the user for input, then alerting it to the user, and throwing it away...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is a project with 2 requirements. Do what I did there with a While loop and then do the exact same thing in a For loop.

Comment: Also, [read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) at the very least before asking a question. Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: @Quentin Well, I wouldn't say that it doesn't make sense, a `while` loop is just a better fit for the problem.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thanks for the link, I have read it and now have the sum of each number working. But still cannot figure out how I can dispay which is the biggest number out of the 3.

Comment: Just to make sure, you should check again, what exactlly is required in your homework. I guess you have to include the input into the loop. And as long as you do not enter "0" there, you have to compare something. When you submit "0", you terminate the loop. Look at a do-while-loop and the "break" command.

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach with less conditions and without any unnecessary loops. Hope you like it =D

```js
var a = Number(prompt("Enter First Number"));
var b = Number(prompt("Enter Second Number"));
var c = Number(prompt("Enter Third Number"));

var biggerNumber = Math.max(a, b, c);
if(a == b && b == c){
  alert("Each number is the same.");
} else {
  var indexBiggerNumber = [a,b,c].indexOf(biggerNumber) + 1;
  alert(`The ${indexBiggerNumber}º number is bigger.`);
}
alert(a + b + c);
```